# Using prompts as variables AppleScript

Tags: applescript, imessage

I am working on a script that sends a message x amount of times, to y person with the message z. However, my main issue comes up in prompting the user to enter x, y and z. This is my base code.

```
on run

  tell application "Messages"
      set targetService to 1st service whose service type = iMessage
      set targetBuddy to buddy "18008888888" of targetService

        repeat 3 times
            send " beef bowl " to targetBuddy
        end repeat

    end tell
end run
```

As you can see, it will send the message " beef bowl " to 18008888888 3 times. However, when I add in prompts, it breaks the code.

```
set numberTo to display dialog "What is the number?" default answer ""
...
set targetBuddy to buddy numberTo of targetService
```

What is wrong with my code?
Thanks!

Comment: output of display dialog in variable numberTo is not a number, but a record made of 2 values : the text returned and the button returned. you must use the 'text returned of numberTo' and coerce it to a number inside a try block to handle if user type something which is not a number !

Answer (score 0):

```
repeat
    try
        set theResult to text returned of (display dialog "blabla"  default answer "" buttons {"OK"} default button "OK")
        set numberTo to (theResult as integer)
        exit repeat
    on error
        -- You may show a warning here to enter a number
    end try
end repeat
```

Use a repeat loop to show the dialog again on wrong entry.
Use the try block to check the coercion (as integer).